# deleting particular rows takes longer time to execute oracle. have to kill the session

Tags: oracle

I have 3 tables Attribute_type, Attribute, Attribute_assignment which is referencing one another. Attribute has Attribute_id + Attribute_type_id, Attribute_assignment has Assignment_id + Attribute_id + Attribute_type_id

There are some stale data in Attribute_assignment, whose parents are deleted and its dangling. So i tried to delete those rows. Few got deleted very easily , but last 4 rows are not getting deleted at all. It just takes long time. Because of this I am not able to add constraints as well.

Please suggest.

Comment: Might there be pending (uncommitted) updates or deletes against those rows, in another session? Can you check for locks and blocking sessions?

Comment: @Alex I was able to get FND_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS after executing SELECT sid, id1 FROM v$lock WHERE TYPE='TM'

SELECT object_name FROM dba_objects WHERE object_id=122778  what should I do after this?